# Cocoapods not working in terminal after native app installaltion

Tags: xcode, rubygems, cocoapods

After I've installed native Cocoapods app and since that moment I have following in terminal:

```
pod --version
1.0.0.beta.3
```

Now I need to use specific version of cocoapods, but even after I remove cocoapods from my mac completely I have same output 1.0.0.beta.3. 
I ununstalled all cocoapods-related stuff listed in `gem list` but version never changed

If I remove the cocoapods.app, I have this:

```
pod --version
[!] Unable to locate the CocoaPods.app application bundle. Please ensure the application is available and launch it at least once.
Trace/BPT trap: 5
```

Could anyone help me to solve this? Maybe I need to change system directory for my pods, but I have no idea where to start looking.

Thanks in advice!

Answer (score 7):

Pay attention to the error message provided:

> Please ensure the application is available and launch it at least once.

Without first launching `CocoaPods.app` at least once the binary `pod` will not have permission to run on your system, resulting in the error message described. Open the app from `/Applications`. This is a bit unintuitive given `pod` is a binary and not an app.

Comment: If I could upvote this more than once, I would. Not at all obvious from the error message - thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I'd installed cocoapods using the instructions on the website with `sudo gem install cocoapods` and got this error but there was no `CocoaPods.app` installed on my system.

So I had to download the app separately from https://cocoapods.org/app, and then run it

Answer (score -1):

This solved by simple replacing the file at path `which pod` with correct one (from other mac)